# Crtl + Alt + PrtSc only works sometimes (while Ctrl+PrtSc works all the time)

Tags: 20.04, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, clipboard

So I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> mapped as default, that is, take a screenshot of the current window and copy it to clipboard. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> is also mapped as default, that is, take a screenshot of the screen and copy it to clipboard. Meanwhile, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> and <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> do the same but, instead of copying to clipboard, save a Picture in ~/Pictures. Now, when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>, sometimes (1 out of 3 in average), the screenshot will be copied, but most of the time there will be a picture saved in the Pictures directory. Why is this happening? Any ideas? How can I check what the commands are doing in real time to see why it doesn't recognise my Ctrl keypress sometimes?

EDIT: The problem seems to be that all keys have to be released at the same time. Now I've tried to do this but the timing's just too nitpicky and it's hard to get it right everytime, of course. Is there a way to map this at keypress. Would this make sense? What's the 'normal' behavior for shortcuts? Or rather, what I instinctively do is press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> then press and release <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> quickly, and then release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, not at the same time. Ah, but when I do this, the shortcut *is* recognized, but it only recognizes Alt, so it should also recognize <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, shouldn't it? Thanks.

Comment: agree it reads it as alt+PrtSc. Also trying this I found that none of the screenshots get copied to the clipboard for me even with the other copy screenshot commands.